# rust FnMut lifetime without use move

Tags: rust

I tried to use FnMut for callback, store in struct with Box , but lifetime issues and mutable issues can't be resolved.
I'm a JavaScript programmer, used to using callback functions, the code structure may not be suitable.

```
struct S {
    f: Box<dyn FnMut(i32)>,
}
impl S {
    fn new<F: FnMut(i32) + 'static>(f: F) -> S {
        S { f: Box::new(f) }
    }
    fn start(&mut self) {
        (*self.f)(2);
        (*self.f)(3);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut i: i32 = 1;
    let mut s: S = S::new(|x| {
        println!("{} + {} = {}", i, x, i + x);
        i = i + x;
    });
    s.start();
    println!("i = {}", i);
}
```

the compiler show the errors:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `i`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src\main.rs:16:27
   |
16 |     let mut s: S = S::new(|x| {
   |                           ^^^ may outlive borrowed value `i`
17 |         println!("{} + {} = {}", i, x, i + x);
18 |         i = i + x;
   |         - `i` is borrowed here
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
  --> src\main.rs:16:20
   |
16 |       let mut s: S = S::new(|x| {
   |  ____________________^
17 | |         println!("{} + {} = {}", i, x, i + x);
18 | |         i = i + x;
19 | |     });
   | |______^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `i` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
16 |     let mut s: S = S::new(move |x| {
   |                           ++++

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `i` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src\main.rs:21:24
   |
16 |       let mut s: S = S::new(|x| {
   |                      -      --- mutable borrow occurs here
   |  ____________________|
   | |
17 | |         println!("{} + {} = {}", i, x, i + x);
18 | |         i = i + x;
   | |         - first borrow occurs due to use of `i` in closure
19 | |     });
   | |______- argument requires that `i` is borrowed for `'static`
20 |       s.start();
21 |       println!("i = {}", i);
   |                          ^ immutable borrow occurs here
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

expect result

```
1 + 2 = 3
3 + 3 = 6
i = 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fn new<F: FnMut(i32) + 'static>(f: F) -> S
```

In this context, the `'static` lifetime annotation means that the actual type of `F` may not be declared to own any references, unless those references refer to values that have static lifetime.

However, the closure you pass captures the outer variable `i` by reference, which does not have static lifetime.  Therefore, the generic lifetime bound `'static` is not satisfied.

There's a few ways you can fix this.  One would be to have `S` take a lifetime parameter, which will enable giving it closures that reference data with a non-static lifetime:

```
struct S<'a> {
    f: Box<dyn FnMut(i32) + 'a>,
}
impl<'a> S<'a> {
    fn new<F: FnMut(i32) + 'a>(f: F) -> S<'a> {
        S { f: Box::new(f) }
    }
    fn start(&mut self) {
        (*self.f)(2);
        (*self.f)(3);
    }
}
```

Note that you also have to drop `s` before you can print `i` because `s` owns a mutable borrow of `i`; the mutable borrow can't coexist with an immutable borrow.  You can drop `s` using `std::mem::drop()` or by declaring it in a new scope that ends before you access `i`.  For example, using the second approach:

```
fn main() {
    let mut i: i32 = 1;
    {
        let mut s: S = S::new(|x| {
            println!("{} + {} = {}", i, x, i + x);
            i = i + x;
        });
        s.start();
    } // s is dropped here, releasing the mutable borrow of i
    println!("i = {}", i);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b546307bc13f5fb101193f8641918ba4))

Where possible, this should be the preferred approach because it adds no runtime overhead.

---

A second approach that is less restrictive but has runtime overhead would be using [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) in combination with [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html).  This approach explicitly gives you in Rust what you have implicitly in JavaScript: shared ownership of values.<sup>1</sup>  To accomplish this, the value exists outside of any of the `Rc` values (on the heap) which are reference-counted handles to the value.

To make this work, `Cell` is required to provide [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html), as you can't get a mutable reference out of an `Rc` unless only one `Rc` exists for the value it handles, which isn't the case here.  `Cell` circumvents this, allowing you to set the contained value even if multiple `Rc`s exist.

Here's an example of how this would apply to this situation, using an `Rc<Cell<i32>>`.  We clone the `Rc` once and move the clone into the closure.  Now both the closure and `main()` have an `Rc` to the same value.  The inner `i32` value will be destroyed when the last `Rc` sharing ownership of it is destroyed.

(Note this uses the definition and implementation of `S` verbatim from your question, which works because an owned `Rc` doesn't count as a reference.  This means the closure will satisfy the `'static` constraint since it doesn't contain any references at all.)

```
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::rc::Rc;

// Definition and implementation of S omitted

fn main() {
    let i = Rc::new(Cell::new(1i32));
    let i2 = i.clone();
    let mut s: S = S::new(move |x| {
        println!("{} + {} = {}", i2.get(), x, i2.get() + x);
        i2.set(i2.get() + x);
    });
    s.start();
    // Dropping s isn't required in this case; both i and i2 can
    // coexist without any problems.
    println!("i = {}", i.get());
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8e1bad00a3c80c2d2c8c9598107fddf7))

---

<sup>1</sup> What you have in JavaScript would actually be closer to `Rc<RefCell<T>>` than `Rc<Cell<T>>`.  Additionally, most JavaScript runtimes don't do reference counting, but instead some type of mark-and-sweep garbage collection.  This is meant to be a comparison about ownership semantics and not a true one-to-one comparison of all possible aspects of JavaScript's object model.

Comment: Is there a way to pass self to closure?  Like `(*self.f)(self, 2);`. The complier shows `cannot borrow '*self' as mutable more than once at a time`.  Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesChu No, that's disallowed because then there's two concurrent references through which `self.f` can be mutated. You _can_ mutably borrow _different fields_ though, like `(*self.f)(&mut *self.something_else, 2)`.